# Remove wrong dashes from get_the_title()

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a particular CPT post that has a dash (-) in its title. I copy this title in a variable `$var` using `get_the_title()` then I create a custom field somewhere else with a value equal to `$var` : `add_post_meta($my_post_id, 'some_name', $var);`

Problem: in the custom field, the dash became a HTML entity with a "&", "#" and a 4-digit number number.

Why, and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_the_title()` is treated with `wptexturize()` by default. That changes the dash.

To fix it remove the filter and reapply it if it was really set:

```
$wptexturize = remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
$title       = get_the_title();

if ( $wptexturize )
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
```